# How to Add a Tab Bar in Master View of UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am building an iPhone / iPad application and I followed Apple's sample to have multiple detailed views in an UISplitViewController application.

I am having an issue with having a tab bar controller on the rootView / masterView of the application. It works fine until I switch detail views..

Then the tab bar goes away from the rootView side, when in Horizontal orientation in vertical orientation it is there but the first tab gets blanked out and then when you click on the secondary tab it comes back.

I am assuming a reference is getting reset. But not sure. Any ideas? Or Any samples out there that you know of trying to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was right in front of me this whole time.

```
    NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.tabBarController, detailViewController, nil];
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```

I originally had this

```
NSArray *viewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.navigationBarController, detailViewController, nil];
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
```